# Count html5 data attributes

Tags: jquery, html

I'm trying to count how many elements (list) have the html data attribute of 'data-facet', but I'm undefined.

Here is what I have tried:

```
$('li').data('facet').length;
```

Any ideas where I've gone wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If `data('facet')` represents an integer, then that would explain the `undefined` result (because you can't run `.length` on an integer). You can fix this by doing `$('li').data('facet').toString().length;` instead, but that's not going to get you the result you want (instead, it will give you the length of the `data-facet` value of the first `li` element).

To get the desired count of `li`s, do this:

```
$('li[data-facet]').length
```

That will give you the number of `li` element that have the `data-facet` attribute.

Comment: It was indeed an integer, @Patrick. Thank you for the help :)